# Django Error: update_qty() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to fix an error when I try to update the number of items in the Order Summary Page which returns,
`update_qty() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'`

There is no specific line indicating the reason for this error. I have included the views for the update_qty for reference

Here is the views.py:

```
class OrderSummaryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'order_summary.html', context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")

@login_required
def update_qty(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item_slug = request.POST.get('item_slug', None)
        # Check for an order_item
        order_item_pk = request.POST.get('order_item', None)
        order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(pk=order_item_pk).first()
        if not order_item:
            messages.info(request, "Product was not in your cart")
            return redirect("product", slug=item_slug)
        # Check for an active order
        order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False).first()
        if not order:
            messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("product", slug=item_slug)
        # Check that order_item is in active order
        if not order_item.order == order:
            messages.info(request, "Product was not in your cart")
            return redirect("product", slug=slug)
        # Update quantities
        action = request.POST.get('action', None)
        if action == "plus":
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "Product quantity was updated.")
        elif action == "minus":
            order_item.quantity -= 1
            if order_item.quantity < 1:
                order_item.delete()
                messages.info(request, "Product was removed from cart.")
            else:
                order_item.save()
                messages.info(request, "Product quantity was updated.")
    return redirect("order-summary")
```

Here is the template:

```
<div class="pull-center">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'core:update-qty' order_item.item.slug %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="minus" class="btn mr-2"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        {{ order_item.quantity }}<button type="submit" name="action" value="plus" class="btn ml-2"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="item_slug" value="{{ order_item.item.slug }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_item" value="{{ order_item.pk }}">
    </form>
</div>                </td>
```

here is the urls:

```
    path('update-qty/<slug>/', update_qty, name='update-qty'),
```

Here is the models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_update_qty(self):
        return reverse("core:update_qty", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
```

Comment: can you show us the `update_qty` view? It seems that you don't give it a keyword argument called `slug`, although your URL pattern proclaims that you do.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I added the `update_qty` view

Comment: thanks. The answer by @Lewis should fix this - but I'm not sure it's the right thing to do. You don't actually appear to *use* a `slug` argument anywhere in that function, and indeed in the case of a GET request it simply redirects anyway. So why do you include a slug in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `slug=None` to your `update_qty` Function based view.

Like so:

```
def update_qty(request, slug=None):
```

*OR*

You can pop the keyword from the `**kwargs`:

```
def update_qty(request, **kwargs):  
    slug = kwargs.pop('slug',None)
```

This will also provide a default value for the variable to `None` if it is not passed as keyword.